# Symfony2 - Utf-8 slug in url

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8

I have a test action in my Controller with a slug parameter.

```
/**
* @Route("/test/{re}")
*/ 
public function test(Request $request,$re) {
        return new Response("<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>".$re."</body></html>");
}
```

Although in Apache worked just fine with utf8 when i uploaded the whole project in iis the result appear like this : ��������.
I know that the controller is in utf-8 because when i try to replace $re with a non latin word is appearing just fine.
Any suggestions?? (Also the url in my browser is fine)

Comment: [Read this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Is the result same with utf8_encode feature on $re?

Comment: Using utf8_encode, the result is something like this : Áñéò

Answer (score 0):

The file's/script's or whole project's encoding may cause such problems. Check if that stuff is set to utf-8.